# Python subprocess Popen not adding all the values for user input

Tags: python, openvpn

Subprocess runs an openvpn command and expects user inputs. Trying to add all the inputs to communicate() function. The input works on all fields except for the last one which asks to verify with (y or n).

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', path+'build-key', self.username], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
proc.communicate(os.linesep.join(['', '', '', '', '', self.username, self.username, self.email, '', '', 'y', 'y']))
```

Current output:

> ```
> Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
> to be sent with your certificate request
> A challenge password []:An optional company name []:Using configuration from /var/easy-rsa/openssl.cnf
> Can't load /root/.rnd into RNG
> 140199966187968:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:../crypto/rand/randfile.c:88:Filename=/root/.rnd
> Check that the request matches the signature
> Signature ok
>
> The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows 
>
> countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
>
> stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'CA'
>
> localityName          :PRINTABLE:'SanFrancisco'
>
> organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'Fort-Funston'
>
> organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'MyOrganizationalUnit'
>
> commonName            :PRINTABLE:'asdasd'
>
> name                  :PRINTABLE:'asdasd'
>
> emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'asdasd'
>
> Certificate is to be certified until Oct  6 11:54:43 2029 GMT (3650 days)
> Sign the certificate? [y/n]:CERTIFICATE WILL NOT BE CERTIFIED: I/O error
> ```

Expecting sign the certificate to accept 'y' but a empty input is taken which is why 'certificate will not be certified' error.

Comment: You aren't sending a newline after that last 'y', so the program you're running cannot read a line of input without hitting EOF.  Adding another `''` to the list is likely to fix this.

Comment: nope, i tried that. doesnt work.

Comment: os.linesep adds newlines

Comment: Tried everything. Not able to get subprocess to add 'y' to sign the certificate. Instead of 'y' nothing is taken as input for that. Hence, 'certificate will not be verified'. makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Used the pexpect module to get the user inputs added automatically. Figured it was the timeout that was needed to 'sign the certificate' and 'commit'. Not sure if subprocess has an option to add timeouts between user inputs.

```
      child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/sh ' + path+'build-key ' + self.username)
      child.sendline('AU')
      child.sendline('WLG')
      child.sendline('\n')
      child.sendline('Company')
      child.sendline('')
      child.sendline(self.username)
      child.sendline(self.email)
      time.sleep(2)
      child.sendline('y')
      time.sleep(2)
      child.sendline('y')
      child.interact()
```